# How to remove tags in html in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, web-services

**When the Webservice hit it shows the response on my textfield like this:
Response i get at when i hit my web service at browser.**

```
        catid = 38;
        created = "May 02 2013";
        "created_by" = 588;
        fulltext = "<p>
```

> But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing
>   leasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete
>   account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great
>   xplorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one
>   rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure
>   ?<\p>
>
> <\p>
>
> But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of
>   denouncing  leasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a
>   complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of
>   the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
>   happiness.

**But i want to replace <\p> <\p> with paragraph change:
I want This response on my iPhone App**

```
       catid = 38;
        created = "May 02 2013";
        "created_by" = 588;
        fulltext = "<p>
```

> But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing
>   leasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete
>   account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great
>   xplorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one
>   rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure
>   ?
>
> But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of
>   denouncing  leasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a
>   complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of
>   the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
>   happiness.

Comment: Does the extra p tag always come in three consecutive tags?

Comment: Yes always....verbumdei

Answer (score 0):

try this function to remove html tag.

```
    - (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {

        NSScanner *theScanner;
        NSString *text = nil;

        theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

        while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

            // find start of tag
            [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ;

            // find end of tag
            [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

            // replace the found tag with a space
            //(you can filter multi-spaces out later if you wish)
            html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:
            [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text]
                                           withString:@" "];
            html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"&nbsp;"] withString:@" "];
        } // while //
        return html;
    }
```

Comment: It just add the space it between,but want it the next paragraph start whenever this sign will show

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the `</p>` tags always come in three because a valid HTML should be giving the tags in pair, e.g. `<p></p>`. But if you are really sure it will always come in three, you can use the NSString instance method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`:

```
- (NSString *)replaceThreeParagraphTags:(NSString *)html {
    return  [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</p></p></p>" withString:@"\n\n"];
}
```

Basically we just replace every occurrences of three `</p>` and replace it with two line breaks `\n` because it seems you want to have a line in between the paragraphs.

Comment: Wait, now the server is giving different results instead of </p></p></p>? Can you just double check on the string returned by the server?

Comment: i Didn't get u.....  </p><p><br></p><p> this change the paragraph normally,but it came in html format so it shows like this only in my iPhone app

Comment: There is simple code what we have use for the API call, I Just filter the response what i get in one the param and it's data my response